# Command Line custom function

Tags: git, unix, terminal, zsh, branching-and-merging

I was playing around in my terminal and I wrote the following basic function in my .zshrc file:

```
function gspecial () {
  git merge $1; rspec;
}
```

With the above when working with separate branches, I can switch to my master branch and call the gspecial with a given branch which will then merge the given branch to master and then immediately after, run the tests.

Calling:

```
git(master)$ gspecial development
```

It performs this sequence:

```
git(master)$ git merge development
git(master)$ rspec
```

My question is, how would I be able (if possible) to extend this function to cater for the following scenario:

```
git(development)$ git checkout master
git(master)$ git merge development
git(master)$ rspec
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: use more parameters in the function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the all-wise @devnull or he might swallow you... No, but seriously, he's right:

```
function gspecial () {
    git checkout $1;
    git merge $2;
    rspec;
}
```

so then:

```
$ gspecial master development
```

will do this:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge development
$ rspec
```

---

### TIP:

Use a more descriptive name, like `git-rspecial` for function names.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it not long after I saw devnull's answer and it's what you described. I think I've spent way too long in front of a screen today :-)